# Is the "abstract" keyword compulsory in classes that have at least on abstract method (Java)?

Tags: java, oop

So I ran into this exam test where we have to determine whether a portion of code is or isn't correct. The execrise focuses on interfaces implementation and subclasses.

Here's the code:

```
interface Figura {
    public void disegna();
    public boolean equals(Object obj);
}

class Ellisse implements Figura {
    public void disegna() {
        System.out.println("Cerchio");
    }
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return (obj instanceof Ellisse);
    }
}

class Cerchio extends Ellisse {
    public void disegna() {
        super.disegna();
        System.out.println("Cerchio");
    }
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return (obj instanceof Cerchio);
    }
}
```

And the question in the exercise is: "would the code still work if we were to delete the `equals` method
from the `Ellisse` class? Why?

The answer I would give is "no, because since `Ellisse` inherits the `equals` method from the `Figura` interface, and since `Ellisse` is not declared `abstract`, it has to implement the method. If it didn't, it would inherit an abstract method and should therefore be declared `abstract`."

And yet the code perfectly works. So what is it that I'm missing?

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: An `equals` method with the same signature is inherited from the `Object` class too, so it works. If it hadn't been defined in a superclass, it would not have worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11882002/user) has pointed out correctly, that:

> An equals method with the same signature is inherited from the Object class too, so it works. If it hadn't been defined in a superclass, it would not have worked.

To the main question:

> Is the “abstract” keyword compulsory in classes that have at least one abstract method (Java)?

Yes. You can go backwards to prove it. If any method is declared as `abstract` the class also must be `abstract`.

But this statement does not work the other way around. A class can be declared `abstract` **without** `abstract` methods. That's totally legal.

Answer (score 1):

Figura is an interface and interfaces are basically like contracts whose methods MUST be implemented by any class that implements them. In this case however the method happens to be equals whose implementation is provided by the object superclass already so even if it gets deleted you're still good.

Comment: +1, but you might want to capitalize "o" in "object" so it's clear you're referring to `java.lang.Object`

Answer (score 1):

Class `java.lang.Object` defines a method with the exact same signature as the `equals()` method in interface `Figura`, namely:

```java
public boolean equals(Object obj)
```

And since every class extends `java.lang.Object` (either directly or indirectly), every class already implements one of the methods in interface `Figura`. Indeed, interface [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) declares the `equals()` method as well, but any class that implements `Comparator` only really needs to implement its `compare()` method for the exact same reason.

Therefore, since class `Ellisse` inherits method `equals()` from its parent class, it doesn't have to explicitly implement that method in order for it to implement interface `Figura`.

Answer (score 0):

equals method exists I believe the comparable interface which is implemented by the object class which is the parent for all object classes.So in short in the code above it kind of just shadows the one in the parent class.

Comment: `Object` doesn't implement `Comparable` AFAIK. The `Comparable` interface has a `compareTo` method instead, which returns an `int`. The `equals` method in `Object` is different